# Is my solution correct? Linear mapping-linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem:

Determine the linear combinations $φ,ψ:R^m→R^n$ of linear mapping.

$φ-2ψ$, where $m=3,n=3$ and $φ$ is the reflection on the plane of the x,y axes,$ψ$ is the orthogonal projection to the plane of $x,y$ axes.

"My solution":

I see that, $φ-2ψ:R^3→R^3$
And I can write that, $(x,y,z)(φ-2ψ)=(x,y,-z)-2⋅(x,y,0)=(-x,-y,-z)$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

If you want you can represents the transformations with the matrices:
$$
\varphi=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \psi=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we have:
$$
\varphi-2\psi=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$